# Angular UI / select2 multiple how to preselect values/options?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

using angular-ui with select2 as follows:

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="search.categories" multiple style="width:300px" data-placeholder="select category">
      <option value="open" >open</option>
      <option value="close" >close</option>
</select>
```

Where and how should I preselect options? By default selected option is only first.Somehow in controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple `<select>` list it's easy:

```
MyController function($scope) {
    $scope.search = {
        categories: 'close'
    };
}
```

For `<input>` it gets trickier because you may need to add a `initSelection` option

Comment: yes worked with categories: ['close','open'] ; but not with 'closed' value. Wtf? Even the auto-completer showing up "close" even closed option value='closed' was declared..

Comment: how to use initSelection in simple case when tags is array of string?